# How to keep the subplot sizes unchanged after putting a colorbar

Tags: matlab

Let us say we have a 1-by-2 subplot and we plot some graphics inside as follows:

```
subplot(1,2,1)
surf(peaks(20))

subplot(1,2,2)
surf(peaks(20))
```

[image]

And then we want to put a colorbar:

```
colorbar
```

[image]

I don't want the right figure squezzed as in the result. How can we put the colorbar out of the rightmost figure in a row of subplots and keep the sizes of them unchanged?

Note: Actually, I need it for plotting images where the colorbar is common and I want to put it on the right. I used this toy example for simplicity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could just extract the position of the first plot and use on the second. MATLAB automatically moves the colorbar to the right when rescaling.

```
f1=figure(1);clf;
s1=subplot(1,2,1);
surf(peaks(20));

s2=subplot(1,2,2);
surf(peaks(20));
hb = colorbar('location','eastoutside');

%% # Solution:
s1Pos = get(s1,'position');
s2Pos = get(s2,'position');
s2Pos(3:4) = [s1Pos(3:4)];
set(s2,'position',s2Pos);



%% # Alternative method. Brute force placement
set(s1,'Units','normalized', 'position', [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.6]);
set(s2,'Units','normalized', 'position', [0.5 0.2 0.3 0.6]);
set(hb,'Units','normalized', 'position', [0.9 0.2 0.05 0.6]);
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Automatic solution is better but brute force lets me to reduce the spacing between the plots such that it is equal to the one between the right plot and the colorbar. Thanks for providing two nice ways.

Answer (score 2):

This is just what I was looking for.  After implementing [Vidar's automatic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10651078/1714410) I came up with a simplification. Get the position of the far right axes BEFORE adding the colorbar, and then just reset the squeezed position to the original:

```
f1=figure(1);clf;
s1=subplot(1,2,1);
surf(peaks(20));

s2=subplot(1,2,2);
surf(peaks(20));
s2Pos = get(s2,'position');

hb = colorbar('location','eastoutside');
set(s2,'position',s2Pos);
```

Comment: I tried it but the labels of the colorbar seem to be outside of the plot.