# placing the colorbar under an image reduces the image size in subplot

Tags: image, matlab, subplot, colorbar

I have the following script which will create a 4x4 plot. The upper two plots are images, while the lower ones are image histograms. 
I Have a problem with the colorbar, and its exponential description (`x10^4`), which will interfere with the titles of the subplots at some point. As a solution I placed the colorbar below the image - however this resulted in a resizing of the upper image, which is not wanted.

The issues could be resolved with either placing the exponential description somewhere else besides the colorbar, but not on the same height as the title. Or placing the colorbar the same way under the image like it is done under histograms.

However, I was not able to find any way to do the above mentioned solutions.

My code looks like the following:

```
clear all
close all

rand_image_1 = uint16(1000*randi(100,100));
rand_image_2 = uint16(1000*randi(100,100));

figure
subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(rand_image_1);
colorbar('southoutside')
caxis auto
title({'A very long description','that will interfere at some point', 'with the text that is written here'})
set(gca,'FontSize',25)
subplot(2,2,2)
imshow(rand_image_2);
caxis auto
colorbar('southoutside')
title({'A very long description','that will interfere at some point', 'with the text that is written here'})
set(gca,'FontSize',25)
subplot(2,2,3)
imhist(rand_image_1);

title({'A very long description','that will interfere at some point', 'with the text that is written here'})
set(gca,'FontSize',25)
subplot(2,2,4)
imhist(rand_image_2);

title({'A very long description','that will interfere at some point', 'with the text that is written here'})
set(gca,'FontSize',25)
```

which produces the following picture:

[image]

Comment: I found a lot of suggestions, searching in the `matlab` tag for "colorbar position subplot". I just think you can know better which of them will be good for you. Maybe this one can help, for example- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649286/how-to-keep-the-subplot-sizes-unchanged-after-putting-a-colorbar/10651078#10651078

Comment: Umm... So what's the desired result exactly?

Comment: A colorbar implementation that will not interfer with the title in any way, either by providing the same colorbar as in the imhistogram down or by adjustng the exponential numer (x*10^4) in a way, so that it is not in the way to the title.  A quick fix is to adjust the TickLabels of the colorbar, so that there is no expenonential number